# Can I rescue data from a WD MyBook 320GB that is not able to mount?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a WD MyBook 320GB. Both Windows and Linux can see the device but are not able to recognize it.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 017: ID 1058:0910 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. MyBook Essential External HDD


$ sudo fdisk -l

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Input/output error
```

When I use the fdisk command I hear a periodic sound coming from the disk, like a retry error.

I am also giving a part of dmesg:

```
[1625730.819325] usb-storage 2-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[1625730.820649] scsi19 : usb-storage 2-1.4:1.0
[1625731.823049] scsi 19:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       3200AAJ External 1.06 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[1625731.823430] sd 19:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[1625731.824213] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[1625731.825457] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[1625731.825460] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[1625731.826314] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[1625731.826317] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[1625731.828578] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[1625731.828580] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[1625744.532603] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 18
[1625744.537914] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[1625744.537918] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[1625744.537920] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1625744.537922] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[1625744.537923] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[1625744.537930] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[1625744.537933] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 0
[1625744.537995] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[1625744.538022] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[1625744.538031]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[1625744.538262] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] READ CAPACITY failed
[1625744.538265] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[1625744.538267] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1625744.538268] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[1625744.538332] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[1625744.538335] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[1625744.538338] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

I am thinking of breaking the case to see if I can get anything by connecting the disk with a SATA cable. Do you think this makes sense, or the retry error can only be caused by a fault of the disk itself, and not the case/usb connector?

Any other suggestions to rescue my data?

EDIT:

I have opened the disk, the usb connector works well with other disks. However I managed to see my disk with another connector, windows says unallocated space, fdisk says:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 *     512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

What tools would you suggest that might help me recover at least part of the data?

Comment: Breaking the case open makes the most sense. Quite often the controller is the only part at fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- remove disk from the plastic case and connect directly. See what happens.
- if you still can't see the drive, buy same HDD model (from eBay?) as donor and replace electronics.

I've done it few times and it works great! I would recommend also SpinRite to recover data when disk is spinning.

**DO NOT OPEN THE DRIVE ITSELF!** Replace just electronics!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'electronics'? If the internal disk is OK, couldn't I just connect it to my motherboard?

Comment: By electronics I mean electronic board - the green board on top of the HDD (or at the bottom - depends what way you look at it!)

Comment: I opened the case and use a dock to connect it to my pc, now I get `Disk /dev/sdb: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
` with fdisk and I am using testdisk to rescue the partition